# Oxyplot Polar Diagram with Categories

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I'd like to create a polar diagram with oxyplot. The circular axis should not consist of integers, but of categories.
Meaning instead of 1 ... 10 it should say Category A Category B ... around the plot.
Neither MagnitudeAxis nor AngularAxis provide the possibility to set "strings" for the axis.
CategoryAxis however cannot be used to plot a polar diagram, because it does not support angles.

My code so far:

```
var plotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "", }; 
plotModel.PlotType = OxyPlot.PlotType.Polar; 
plotModel.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.AngleAxis() 
{ 
    MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid, 
    //MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot, 
    MajorStep = 1, 
    CropGridlines = false, 
    StartAngle = 450, 
    EndAngle = 90, 
    Minimum = 0, 
    Maximum = 19
});

plotModel.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.MagnitudeAxis()
{
    MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
    Minimum = 0,
    Maximum = 5,
    MajorStep = 1,
    MinorStep = 1
});

var newValues = new OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries { Title = "New Values", StrokeThickness = 1 };

int i = 0;

foreach(var dataRow in details)
{
    newValues.Points.Add(new DataPoint(dataRow.NewValue, i++)); //instead of i++ I would like to put a string of the object dataRow, but this is not supported...
}
```

In lack of examples and documentation online, this is my last hope to find some help...

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. What have you tried so far and what is your current issue?

Comment: code provided... I don't know how this helps, because I'm searching for an idea (not final code) but if it helps I happily supply it...

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the LabelFormatter property is what you need.  The code below creates labels 'Category A', 'Category B'...'Category S' around the outside of the plot.  It does this because (char)65 is 'A', (char)66 is 'B' etc.

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.AngleAxis()
{
    MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
    MajorStep = 1,
    CropGridlines = false,
    StartAngle = 450,
    EndAngle = 90,
    Minimum = 0,
    Maximum = 19,
    LabelFormatter = d => $"Category {(char)(d+65)}"
});
```

Comment: Thanks that´s a good hint, however I dont really want to put just Cat A, Cat B but the real names of the category, which are totally independent from each other (A better example would be: Cars, Trucks, MotorCycles, etc...). Does this also work with the LabelFormatter?

Comment: This is why it's better if you say exactly what it is you're trying to do with a code example.  It makes it much easier to give you a helpful answer :-)  I think all you need is a mapping from the default numeric labels to the text you need, which you could hardcode or create a dictionary to do.  I'll expand my answer to show that.  It's quite an odd polar chart though.

Comment: Why is this odd? It shows pretty compact how good a score on a category is... It's probably not as readable as if you put it just straight, but it looks fancier... That's the request I got from business ;) Next problem is, however, now the label of the axis should be always horizontally, it currently rotates with the diagram :-/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of Rich N I was able to find a (nasty) workaround by myself:

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.AngleAxis() 
{ 
    MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid, 
    //MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Dot, 
    MajorStep = 1, 
    CropGridlines = false, 
    StartAngle = 450, 
    EndAngle = 90, 
    Minimum = 0, 
    Maximum = 19,
    LabelFormatter = d => myCategoryList[Convert.ToInt32(d)] //myCategoryList is a list of strings
});
```